# How to take sum of only the second column of a matrix / multidimensional array using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

My array has two columns, the first being the letters of the alphabet (as single letter strings), and the second a number. I want to find the sum of these numbers but I get errors due to the strings.

I found out you can do axis=0 in the numpy.sum function to get the sum of the columns, which might be closer to what I need.

```
import numpy as np
str = "aaabcc"
foo = [
    ["a", str.count("a")],
    ["b", str.count("b")],
    ["c", str.count("c")],
    ]
print(np.sum(foo, axis=0)
```

If there is a way to get the sum of the second column without the axis=0 that would work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
np.array(foo)[:, 1].astype('int').sum()
```

Output:

```
6
```

Comment: Yes this does just what I need it to do. It seems that np.array(foo)[:, 1] returns the numbers as strings, do you know why this is? Furthermore why can't you write foo[:][1] for example instead of np.array(foo)[:][1]?

Comment: numpy arrays are cast as single data type.  Since there are strings, everything get casted as a string in numpy.

Comment: np.array(foo)[:] returns the entire array then np.array(foo)[:][1] will get ony the second row,  [:, 1] is a 2-d slice of getting all rows and the second column.  Need look at numpy docs to understand indexing and slicing.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
sum(i[1] for i in foo)

Out[1]:
    6
```

Comment: You don't need the brackets inside... `sum(i[1] for i in foo)`